# Why use differencing and Box-Cox in time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, data-transformation, stationarity

Why use Differencing and Box-Cox transformation in a time series? From what I read the usefulness of the procedures are

- Differencing: Making a time series stationary and stabilize the mean
- Box-Cox: stabilize the variance

Is there anything else behind it?

I know that there is some useful properties in a [Stationary Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process), but why is so important have it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The Box-Cox transformation is a family of power transformations** indexed by a **parameter lambda**.  Whenever you use it the parameter needs to be **estimated** from the data.  In time series the process could have a non-constant variance. If the variance changes with time, the process is **nonstationary**.  It is often desirable to transform a time series to make it **stationary**.  Sometimes after applying Box-Cox with a particular value of lambda the process may look stationary. It is sometimes possible that even if after applying the Box-Cox transformation the series does not appear to be stationary, **diagnostics from ARIMA modeling** can then be used to decide if **differencing or seasonal differencing** might be useful to remove **polynomial trends or seasonal trends** respectively.  After that, the result might be an ARMA model that is stationary. If diagnostics confirm the orders p and q for the ARMA model, the AR and MA parameters can then be estimated.

Regarding other possible uses of Box-Cox in the case of a series of iid random variables that **do not appear to be normally distributed** there may be a particular value of lambda that makes the data **look approximately normal.**

Presumably, this could be applied in regression or time series to the error term.

Comment: Is there models for nonstationary time series?

Comment: If you start with an apparent nonstationary process and then transform to stationarity isn't the final model a model for a nonstationarity? If you are asking if there is a model that will give a good solution for every type of nonstationarity probably not.

Comment: I mean what you do when even after transformations the process isn't stationary? Is not possible do anything?

Comment: If this was for your time series class you should have used the tag self-study. Since the question is open you may still need to add it.